# How to access user control properties if i load it programatically?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, user-controls

i loaded my user control (.ascx) programmatically like: `LoadControl("~/Controls/mycontrol.ascx")`. Every thing was ok until today when i added two members to my control:

```
public StuffType stuffType { get; set; }

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch (stuffType)
    {
        case CardType.A:
            FillGvStuff();
            break;
        case CardType.B:
            FillGvExStuff();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }       
}
```

how can i access StuffType?

i found a kind of [solution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c0az2h86%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you'd do something like this:

```
MyControl ctrl = (MyControl)LoadControl("~/Controls.mycontrol.ascx");
ctrl.stuffType = ...;
// put control somehwere
```

Basically, when you load it, assign it to a variable and cast it as its type and you should then have access to its methods and properties

You might also want to move your page_load event into page_prerender so that you are definetly setting the property before the page_load event occurs in the control